# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Update value at specific time of the day, everyday

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Please help me. I am using Cloud Functions for Firebase to write a back-end script for my Android application. This script is supposed to update a value in the Firebase Database once per day, at a specific time of the day, automatically.

The problems are:

1. I managed to make the function be triggered when that value from Firebase is changed(with onWrite() event), but that's not really automatically.
2. I couldn't find the best, or one of the best solution for the code, on how to specific the moment of the day when the value will be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a Database trigger, use an HTTP trigger with a third party cron job service. Check out these resources to learn more:

[Timing Cloud Functions with HTTP Triggers and Cron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA&t=2s)

[Cloud Functions Samples - Delete Unused Accounts Cron](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron)

Comment: Thanks for help! I will try this way and come back after that

Comment: Since that great video, I have been thinking on how to do it with out using a third party, and I have a really hacky way to do it. Using Firebase job dispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android you can make any Android device to do a cron job, you could set a firebase cron job to set a value in a node and listen to that with Functions... maybe leaving that device charging.... always... like a server... a very small server

Comment: The answer is correct. Thank you again!